# Amazon Fire 10 navigation bar missing, replaced with red line

Tags: amazon-kindle-fire, navigation-bar

My neighbor has lost the navigation bar on her Amazon Kindle Fire 10 (9th generation) and has a thick red line instead.

She does not have the Gmail app. She has never enabled Alexa. "Show Mode" is unchecked, which removes the red line, but it comes back when opening any site. At the moment, she has to reboot the tablet every time she wants to change a screen.

Other than a total refresh to factory specs, are there any suggestions?

Comment: If you rotate the tablet so that the content rotates, does the red line stay or also rotates?

Comment: Based on quick research, looks like the red line does relate to Show Mode or Alexa being muted, e.g. [Amazon Forum - There’s a red line at the bottom of my tablet and I can’t get to the home screen. It’s fully charged and I’ve restarted several times](https://www.amazonforum.com/s/question/0D54P00007IDKUASA5/theres-a-red-line-at-the-bottom-of-my-tablet-and-i-cant-get-to-the-home-screen-its-fully-charged-and-ive-restarted-several-times). Could you recheck it?

Comment: Answer to comments: The red line does rotate with the screen.I turned Show Mode off, and Alexa have never been activated/enabled/turn on, on this Fire.  She does own an Echo, but it's was only used with her older Fire, since retired.When Show Mode is turned off, the red line usually stays until restarted. Then, Show Mode comes back On. Sometimes the red line comes back as soon as restarted.